# Best way to make cartoon style hair?

Tags: hair

I'm not experienced user. I searched bunch of different methods to make hair in blender internal. But I want to know **which is the best & most realistic (modeled) method to make (Cartoon-Style) hair in blender internal?**

[image]

like This! It's shape looks realistic.

Comment: Can you add an image to your Post of something similar?
Besides that imho, realistic hair and cartoon style hair are opposites and don't really go together.

Comment: Sorry I meant realistic modeled hair (not in material)...I want Cartoon Style material for hair but realistic shape ;) @bstnhnsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of video tutorials on this subject that will provide a much better answer than we can here. I would suggest this one by Kent Trammel from CG Cookie:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7mISvVzJk

The result isn't exactly like the image you posted, but is similar enough that you should be able to adapt the techniques to your situation.

The other way to make hair like you want is to sculpt it. There are a couple of good tutorials online about how to do that. Even tutorials for other programs like ZBrush can be a good way to find out how to do it. CG Cookie has a great tutorial on how to sculpt hair, but it appears that a subscription of sorts is required for this one (might be free, not sure). Here is the trailer for the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXKYN5qJX1c

Comment: Yes, That's right method. But I want that kind of hair which you can see in image that I have posted. I was hoping to find different approach.

Comment: The other alternative is to sculpt the hair. My guess would be that is how the original image you posted was done (at least to start with). There are a number of good tutorials on that as well (I think CG Cookie has a good one on their YouTube channel).

Comment: Can you post a link?

Comment: Turns out the tutorial I was thinking of is one you have to subscribe/pay for, maybe it was free in the past, but as far as I can tell it's not free now. This is the trailer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXKYN5qJX1c

Comment: This is a tutorial for ZBrush, but the techniques are pretty software independent. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWF4SKhWKfI

Comment: The Trailer you posted the link of, was helpful it gived me the hint. I try to watch the whole video some how. @brenticus

Comment: Is there anyway you can change this comment into answer? Otherwise post answer to my question with adding two or more sentences & adding the link that you have posted in your comment.... Anyway Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited my answer to include the link and some more detials.